# How to output certain lines from a batch script result to a file

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I want to only output certain lines from a command result into another file.
This is my script

```
@echo off
del "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\script1results.txt"

cd C:\Users\ndujakov\DIG
for /f %%a in (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\script1inputs.txt) do (
dig %%a >> C:\Users\admin\Desktop\script1results.txt
)
```

Here are the results and what I want to specifically output

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6-P1 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6710
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     248 IN  A   172.217.160.206    <---This one

;; Query time: 1 msec                          <---This one
;; SERVER: 10.231.0.106#53(10.231.0.106)
;; WHEN: Fri Feb 02 08:25:55 Pacific Standard Time 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

Comment: how to decide, which lines?

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `findstr /?` for help on this command. You can specify multiple search strings which are OR interpreted to get a filtered output written into a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can get started with this batch file to filter your results :

```bat
@echo off
set "Inputfile=result.txt"
set "TmpFile=%Tmp%\%random%.txt"
set "OutPutFile=FilterResult.txt"
(FindStr /IR /C:"[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]" /C:"msec" "%inputfile%")>"%TmpFile%"
(Findstr /IV "server" "%TmpFile%")>"%OutPutFile%"
Start "" "%OutPutFile%" & del "%TmpFile%"
```

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.